# Callback NodeJS

Tags: node.js, callback, wait

Like every new programmer with asynchronous technology I would like to do some tasks before others. 
Then I did research on the topic and many peoples from the others language spoke about my own callback and to write something like that :

```
function persistMAP(jsonData, callback, res) {
  //Deck persistance
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      var rowData = new DeckDatabase({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        DeckNumber: Number(jsonData.Deck[i].DeckNumber),
        x: Number(jsonData.Deck[i].x),
        y: Number(jsonData.Deck[i].y),
      });
      rowData.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        for (var i = 0; j = jsonData.Units.length, i < j; i++) {
          (function(i) {
            console.log(jsonData.Units[i]);
            var unit = new MapDatabase({
              UnitID: jsonData.Units[i].UnitID,
              TypeID: Number(jsonData.Units[i].TypeID),
              x: Number(jsonData.Units[i].x),
              y: Number(jsonData.Units[i].y),
              _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(((jsonData.Units[i].Code).toLowerCase()) + 'dd40c86762e0fb12000003'), // mongoose.Types.ObjectId(jsonData.Units[i].Code + 'dd40c86762e0fb12000003')
              MainClass: jsonData.Units[i].MainClass,
              Orientation: jsonData.Units[i].Orientation,
              Postion: jsonData.Units[i].Postion,
              Deck: String(rowData._id)
            });

            unit.save(function(err) {
              if (err) return console.log(err);
            });
          })(i);
        }

      });

    })(i);
  }

  callback(res);
};


persistMAP(data, function(res) {
      //Now do my other task  });
```

But it doesn't work... I mean my callback(res) still execute in the same time that my code. 
So I would like to know if it possible with nodeJS because for the moment I'm using Timeout function ...

Comment: 1) Using `var i` in both nested loops will result in one shadowing the other. 2) `unit.save()` is async. You need to use `await` or promises (Promise.all()) to wait for all instances to finish save()'ing and call your callback only afterwards.

Comment: Ok so if I understood I shoud put the word await in the declaration of unit.save and when you say  'and call your callback only afterwards' I suppose i should put my call in the callback of unit.save??